# Teamviewer "show black screen" keeps the screen black after disconnecting

Tags: display, teamviewer

I connected to my laptop using TeamViewer from another machine and I had selected the option "Show Black Screen". After disconnecting I can't get my laptop display back :(

I can see the screen contents when I look to close to the display, I tried to adjust the brightness, but still the same. I have googled it and found there is a chance this happens if the TeamViewer version is old, so I updated TeamViewer on both machines and tried connecting and disconnecting again, but still the display is not ready.

How can I solve this?